# I wanted to Know that how can I give ingore to 0000-00-00 in my config file

Tags: database, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I wanted to know that how can I give ignore to 0000-00-00 in my config file so that I didn't get an error of invalid value for this Zero-Date 0000-00-00 in my site database.

Comment: Where/how/why are you using this date format? A lot of code depends on certain columns returning a valid date, so there isn't going to be a switch you can just flip.

Comment: Brother, I am using this date in my database for a null value, and to 1000-01-01 then It shows incorrect DateTime value

Comment: Is this a custom table? There is no code in your question